# spark-jobserver - managing multiple EMR clusters

Tags: spark-jobserver

I have a production environment that consists of several (persistent and ad-hoc) EMR Spark clusters.

I would like to use one instance of `spark-jobserver` to manage the job JARs for this environment in general, and be able to specify the intended `master` right when I `POST /jobs`, and not permanently in the config file (using `master = "local[4]"` configuration key).

Obviously I would prefer to have `spark-jobserver` running on a standalone machine, and not on any of the `masters`.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a SparkMasterProvider

https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/job-server/src/spark.jobserver/util/SparkMasterProvider.scala

A complex example is here https://github.com/spark-jobserver/jobserver-cassandra/blob/master/src/main/scala/spark.jobserver/masterLocators/dse/DseSparkMasterProvider.scala

I think all you have to do is write one that will return the config input as spark master, that way you can pass it as part of job config.